# hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, autocommit, disable

I am opening transaction using TransactionInterceptor and using HibernateTransactionManager and com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource as datasource.

I have set autocommit value for datasource and hibernate property hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit values as follows

```
<property name="autoCommit" value="false"/>

<prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit">true</prop>
```

Even then the transaction is getting opened much before it is required.

5.3.1.Final version of hibernate-core is used for the above.

I have used the following references.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9261

https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-always-use-hibernate-connection-provider_disables_autocommit-for-resource-local-jpa-transactions/

Please let me know in case anything else was required to be done or what is the exact meaning of delay.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: auto commit has nothing to do with starting a transaction. This has to do with hibernate, again, disabling auto-commit (which is already done by Spring). Setting read-only is a time consuming operation (on some databases) and as such doing it twice has an impact. But this has nothing to do with the point where the tx is started.

Comment: @M.Deinum Apparently, in Hibernate this has something to do with the point where the tx is started. And this "something do to" is described in the posts linked by the post owner and also here https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11542 . But sure, this is just a Hibernate-specific relation.

Comment: That issue describes what I'm saying that it doesn't delay the transaction or obtaining of the connection. It merely disables setting the property again.

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-always-use-hibernate-connection-provider_disables_autocommit-for-resource-local-jpa-transactions/ does seem to suggest it delays connection acquisition. I must say I don't understand the logic in the article and why they can only delay if they know that auto-commit is disabled already by the connection pool.

Comment: I can see only this property: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.autocommit` in my `application.properties`, am i doing something wrong or it was just renamed to this one from the one you mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from configuring autocommit as false in hibernate as you did, you also need to set autocommit to false at the connection pool level. Otherwise, it won't be effective as in your case. Say, for Hikari pool you need to configure as below:

```
HikariConfig hikariConfig = super.hikariConfig( dataSource );

hikariConfig.setAutoCommit( false );
```